# Network foor loop async

Tags: flutter, http, dart, response, dio

I want to a lot of request in for loop.This is my network method.

```
Future postdata<T, F extends ApiResponseFromJson>({
        @required T? requestmodel,
        @required F? responsemodel,
        @required String? path,
      }) async {
        try {
          final response = await dio.post(path!, data: requestmodel);
          print(ApiPath.API_URL + path);
          if (response.data is List) {
            return List<F>.from(
                (response.data).map((e) => responsemodel!.fromJson(e)));
          }
          return responsemodel!.fromJson(response.data);
        } on DioError catch (e) {
          final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e).toString();
          showSnackBarDialog("Hata", errorMessage, const Icon(Icons.error))
};



 List<CarModel> carModel=[CarModel(),CarModel(),CarModel()...]


 Future<ResponseModel?> postData(int index) async {
    responseModel.carModel = carModel[i];
    responseModel= await _networkService
        .postdata<RequestModel, ResponseModel>(
            requestmodel: requestModel,
            responsemodel: ResponseModel(),
            path: ApiPath.API_DATA_LINK); 

    return responseModel;
  }


 _allListModel() async {
        for (var i = 0; i < carModel.length; i++) {
          differentList.add(await postData(i));
        }
```

I have different list and i need request list of lenght.But in for loop response always waiting the other index. But i dont need wait. Cause `networkModel` goes to list of lenght different API and i don't know which one result is coming to first.

I want to request in for loop and i don't need to the other index. How can i do ?

Comment: now you can see

Comment: use `final responses = await Future.wait(List.generate(carModel.length, postData));`

Answer (score 0):

This code call all request at once, just remove `await` and the method `then` is called when request end:

```
_allListModel() {
      for (var i = 0; i < carModel.length; i++) {
        postData(i).then((value) {
          differentList.add(value);
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to wait all futures. ı need to add list which one is coming

Comment: That code add to list as each one arrives, the problem is you dont know when all are finished

Comment: Yes thats true , I don't know which one request is complete . Whichever request finishes first, I need to add it to the list.

Comment: into each `postData(i).then((value) {
print('request'+i.toString()+' end');
          differentList.add(value);
        });` you can know when finish that request. Now, if use for example `Completer` class you can control when all are finished with a variable like `counter` into last code shared

Comment: this method always giving error   I/chatty  (31196): uid=10183(com.example.app) 1.ui identical 2 lines .   and function is working but postData not working.

Comment: error or warning? it is when same line is printed by debugger i think

Comment: bro ı tried many thing . Now ı checked Db record and have just list of first index. The other list of index is going to API but response is a always first list of index.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Future.wait` to wait for multiple futures. You start all of them and then you wait until all are done and add all the results to the list.

```
Future<void> _allListModel() async {
  var futures = <Future<>>[]
  
  for (var i = 0; i < carModel.length; i++) {
    futures.add(postData(i));
  }

  var responses = await Future.wait(futures);

  differentList.addAll(responses);
}
```